# Filtering an array with two drop-down list parameters

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a questions template that determines the appropriate questions from a list based on the target's (e.g. a company) size and complexity. The 'size' drop-down list includes three categories: small, medium, large. The 'complexity' element is more of a yes/no drop-down, as it adds additional questions to the template if selected yes.

On the first worksheet is the final template that displays the filtered array using IMPORTRANGE, and the drop-down lists. On the second sheet are both the unfiltered and filtered question lists.

Now, my problem is filtering the list so that both parameters are accounted for. I have tried nested IF functions, but the problem is it stops on the first TRUE, so it only ever considers one of the parameters (as the 'size' parameter must be selected).

This is the very untidy nested IF function that I've used (without the complexity parameter):

=IF('Worksheet'!Cell = "Option 1";(QUERY(A3:C;"SELECT * WHERE C = 'Option 1'"));IF('Worksheet'!Cell = "Option 2";(QUERY(A3:C;"SELECT * WHERE C = 'Option 2'"));IF('Worksheet'!Cell = "Option 3";(QUERY(A3:C;"SELECT * WHERE C = 'Option 3'")))))

Is there a way to add the 'complexity' parameter into a nested IF function, or use some other function that considers both parameters?

Answer (score 0):

try just:

```
=QUERY(A3:C; "where C = '"&Worksheet!A1&"'")
```